# How to fetch Google contacts?

Tags: google-contacts-api

I want to create an app that requires to fetch Gmail contact list  for sending  friends request  so kindly give all link that are applicable to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the steps given at link   and like my answers

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1